# Android 2.2 app on HTC Hero running Android 1.5

Tags: android

I have an application developed using Android 2.2 SDK. Can i port it on HTC Hero running Android 1.5?

Thanks
Dheepak

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes, but you haven't given us enough information.  Most of the API is largely the same so it may work simply by changing the "target" to whatever the 1.5 API level is.  But it also may require hours upon hours of work if it relies heavily on API calls that are new to any version of Android after 1.5.  It depends entirely on what the application does and how it does it.

We simply don't have enough information to give you an answer that is worth anything.

My suggestion would be to just change the compile target to Android 1.5 (I think the API level is 3...but I'm not sure) and see what happens.  You can then go about fixing the errors that are reported.  I would suggest looking through the errors though to make sure it isn't some fundamental problem with the calls you're using.